# How to route navigation in Angular to the same page and reload

Tags: angular, angular-routing

### Summary

I am trying to set up navigation to the same component that dynamically loads different content, and can't get that to load properly.

### Details

I have a simple application with a route set up in `app.module.ts`:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'posts/:slug', component: PostComponent}
];
```

and a router import declaration of:

```js
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { onSameUrlNavigation: "reload"}),
```

I added the "reload" from [reading the documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterConfigOptions#onSameUrlNavigation). In `PostComponent` I set the slug to a property in `OnInit()`:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.slug = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('slug') as string;
}
```

And when I declare this on my `post.component.html`:

```html
{{ slug }}
<a routerLink="/posts/through-a-router-link">Through A Router Link</a>
```

It correctly loads the page the first time, however when I click on the link, it updates my URL to `localhost:4200/posts/through-a-router-link` but my content doesn't refresh (i.e. the `OnInit()` doesn't run).

How do I navigate to the same component with a different slug and force a refresh of the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are accessing the slug variable on the `snapshot`. The `snapshot` only provides a value which can be found for the first time (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70797915/6942210)). When you access the `paramMap` without the `snapshot` you get an Observable which can be subscribed like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap) => {
        this.slug = paramMap.get('slug') as string;
    });
}
```

So the `this.slug` variable will be updated every time when the paramMap is updated with a new value.

Comment: that makes perfect sense, thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

When that page is already loaded, it doesn't destroy and create the same component. Rather, it will keep everything loaded and just update the route. As such, you'll need to use the router service to listen to changes in the path:

```js
  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        // User has navigated to new page.
        // Update content.
      }
    })
  }
```